JavaFX 11 Webview issue with webpages containing base64 encoded images
I'm working on a small eclipse plugin (for eclipse-rcp-2021-06) based on JavaFX 11.0.2 and openjdk 11.0.11 (don't blame me that is old)
What I have is an WebView which loads different html files.
For some files, which contains svg with base64 encoded images, class com.sun.webkit.MainThread not found error raised.
In VM arguments apart of others, I have:
-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.fx.osgi
-Defxclipse.java-modules.dir=${eclipse_home}\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib 

Also all javafx libs are added into JRE system libraries.
Except of webview error, all components are working well.
I have tried to use this VM args but with no success.
--module-path %PATH_TO_FX%
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

I know that in javaFX 17 this issue was solved, but there must be a workaround fix for this.
Thank you for support

You only got 13 views in 9 days. I added the Java tag and the JavaFX tag. Hopefully, that will increase the number of people who see this.
